# Red color black for mega menu

Tags: color

Red, white and gray are the brand colors for this particular site and I wanted to get some thoughts on using the color red on the mega menu on click. What are the best practices when using spans of color? The Nav is already red.

[image: red site navigation]

Comment: When you say broad is it adding to the cognitive load of the user? Gray was my second option. Thank you.

Comment: First impression is very "in your face"... perhaps keep the nav-bar part (logo through search icon) red and make the rest grey? Possibly with a narrow red border around the main part?

Comment: Thanks, Triphound, these are all great feedback and appreciated.